# Python pexpect won't work

Tags: python, time, cron, pexpect

I have a question about pexepct in Python.
What I wanna to do is, run my script at some time, and then stop it at some time.
Pexpect wont work like it should. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, so can you give me some advice on my code below?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

date  = '2014-09-06'
start = '15:32'
stop  = '16:30'

import pexpect, sys
string = 'at '+start+' '+date

child = pexpect.spawn(string)
child.expect('warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh')
child.expect('at> ')
child.sendline('./run_script.py\n')
child.expect('at> ')
child.sendline('\^D\n')
print child.before
```

The problem is, when all commands send pexepct wont create a job.
Any advice should be great.

Comment: _"Pexpect wont work like it should."_ What _exactly_ don't work as it should ?

Comment: BTW, you could invoke `at` using pipe/redirection. That needs to launch a shell (`subprocess... shell=True`), but will get rid of `pexpect`. something like `echo './run_script.py' | at ...`.

Comment: Pexpect wont create a job after sending lines.

Answer (score 0):

Here the way ctrl+d is sent is not valid. Even after sending ctrl+d, the script has to wait for couple of seconds for the at command to register the new job before closing the pexpect spawn object.

```
import pexpect
import sys
import time

prompt = "at>"

try:
    conn = pexpect.spawn("at 14:30 2019-06-14")
    conn.logfile = sys.stdout
    conn.expect(prompt)
    conn.sendline("touch /tmp/test.txt")
    conn.expect(prompt)
    conn.sendcontrol("d")
    time.sleep(3)
    conn.close()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

After executing the above code snippet, run the command 'atq' in the linux terminal  to verify that job has been queued up.

```
# atq
52  Fri Jun 14 14:30:00 2019 a root
```